# Excluded from Google: Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical

Tags: seo, google-search-console

In google search console, it reports my URL is duplicate and excluded because the submitted URL is not selected as cannonical.

In the inspection result page, it sasys:

> User-declared canonical: https://a.b.c/index.html
>
> Google-selected canonical: https://a.b.c/index.html

It is noticed that the only difference is the scheme. For URL submmited, it is "https", but for selected by Google, it is "http".

In fact, both the above URLs are one same page. I have put the canonical tag (href="https://a.b.c/index.html") in the page header meta.

Why does Google still select http as cannonical, regardless my assignment?
How can I fix it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonical tags are a suggestion and just one of the signals used to help Google determine which URL to chose.

A stronger signal is to 301 redirect the http pages to the https ones. That will also force your users to a secured and safer environment.

I suspect Google may be choosing the http versions if they have more links to them. Try and update any links you control to go to the https versions.

Comment: Have made http version of the URL a 301 redirection, but nothing changed. It is very strange why google choose http version as canonical one. Because almost all link we send out are https version.  Maybe I should wait for a more time.

Comment: It will take some time. Google has to crawl the URLs to realise they redirect.

Comment: Yes, it now says the canonical URL is the inspected one. Thank you very much!